# Nuxt VueJS There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

nuxtJS when compiling gives an error, Google did not help, it is written that when declaring capital letters occurs, however, I get an error directly in node_modules, and not in my components

```
    [HMR] bundle 'client'
has 6 warnings
vendors.app.js: 47737. / node_modules / base64 - js / index.jsThere are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
case -semantic.Use equal casing.Compare these module identifiers: * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ base64 - js\ index.js Used by 1 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ base64 - js\ index.js Used by 1 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js. / node_modules / buffer / index.jsThere are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
case -semantic.Use equal casing.Compare these module identifiers: * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js Used by 3 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ jszip\ lib\ support.js * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js Used by 2 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ core - util - is\ lib\ util.js. / node_modules / ieee754 / index.jsThere are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
case -semantic.Use equal casing.Compare these module identifiers: * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ ieee754\ index.js Used by 1 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ ieee754\ index.js Used by 1 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js. / node_modules / isarray / index.jsThere are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
case -semantic.Use equal casing.Compare these module identifiers: * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ isarray\ index.js Used by 1 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ buffer\ index.js * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ isarray\ index.js Used by 2 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ readable - stream\ lib\ _stream_readable.js. / node_modules / process / browser.jsThere are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
case -semantic.Use equal casing.Compare these module identifiers: * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ process\ browser.js Used by 2 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ setimmediate\ setImmediate.js * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ process\ browser.js Used by 2 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ readable - stream\ lib\ _stream_readable.js. / node_modules / webpack / buildin / global.jsThere are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
case -semantic.Use equal casing.Compare these module identifiers: * C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ webpack\ buildin\ global.js Used by 8 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ babel - loader\ lib\ index.js ? ? ref--2 - 0!C : \ dashboard\.nuxt\ client.js * C : \ dashboard\ node_modules\ webpack\ buildin\ global.js Used by 4 module(s), i.e.C: \ dashboard\ node_modules\ readable - stream\ lib\ _stream_writable.js
```

someone have idea's?

my nuxt.config.js

```
const pkg = require("./package");

const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require("vuetify-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "spa",
  head: {
    title: "Vue Template",
  },      
  css: [
    "~/assets/style/theme.styl",
    "~/assets/style/app.styl",
    "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css"
  ],
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/vuetify",
    "~/plugins/vee-validate",
    "~/plugins/dxdatagrid",
    "~/plugins/vue-notifications"
  ],
  modules: [],
  build: {
    vendor: ["axios", "vuetify", "vue-notifications", "mini-toastr"],
    transpile: ["vuetify/lib"],
    plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()],   
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }      
};
```

Comment: did u tried remove lock file and node modules and reinstall?

Comment: of course I tried

Answer (score 0):

The error happens if you are importing the same file with a difference in capitalization at different place.
e.g;- below I am importing same component 'AppControlInput' with a difference in 'ui' capitalization. In the first case, 'ui' is lowercase while in other 'ui' is uppercase.

1. import AppControlInput from "~/components/ui/AppControlInput";
2. import AppControlInput from "~/components/UI/AppControlInput";

Just make sure you have the same capitalization in every place you import component.